# HTML + CSS - fit 2 divs within 100vh

Tags: html, css, viewport

I'm having an issue with my code and it seems easy but I can't get my head around it.

I'm trying to make the main `div` full `vh` so the content auto height should be `100vh` - the height of the title box.

However, I keep getting the scroll bar for the length of the title box. Any fix?

Full HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>

<style>
    .maindiv {
        min-height: 500px;
        height: 100vh;
        background: red;
    }

    .maindiv-inner {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background: blue;
    }

    .maindiv-inner-content {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background: yellow;
    }

    .titlediv {
        height: 200px;
    }
</style>

<div class="maindiv">
    <div class="maindiv-inner">
        <div class="titlediv">
            Title 1
        </div>
        <div class="maindiv-inner-content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I fI understood correctly you want to keep `titlediv` at the top and only the content in `maindiv-inner-content` is scrollable. Is it right?

Comment: @AdamP. - yes i want the content to take the full vh minus the title height. so the page should not be scrollable.

Comment: As you are using `vh` you proably do not need this to work in every legacy browser, so you could use a flexbox or grid layout instead?

Comment: Adam, here is your code snippet as a codepen: https://codepen.io/ingosteinke/pen/MWjEWpM

Comment: @IngoSteinke - still get the scrollbar

Comment: Look for my sample: https://codepen.io/adampweb/pen/oNzGNYB

Answer (score 1):

You can easily solve this issue by changing some of the CSS classes like this.

```css
body{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

.maindiv
{
  /*min-height:500px;*/
  height: 100vh;
  background:red;
  position: relative;
}

.maindiv-inner
{
  position: relative;
  background:blue;
}

.maindiv-inner-content
{
  position:fixed;
  background:yellow;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

.titlediv
{
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    
        <body>  
            <div class="maindiv">
                <div class="maindiv-inner">
          
            <div class="titlediv">
              Title 1
            </div>
            
            <div class="maindiv-inner-content">
              <div>Something in Content</div>
            </div>
                </div>
    
            </div>
        </body>  
    </html>
```

Comment: When i put something in the content, the content div does not take the rest of the page.

Comment: I just fixed the content div, if my answer is correct please mark it as the answer, Good luck my friend.

Answer (score 0):

does the following provide what you want?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>

    <body>

        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
            }

            .maindiv
            {
                min-height:500px;
                height:100vh;
                background:red;
                width:100%;
                background:blue;
            }

            .maindiv-inner-content
            {
                height: calc( 100% - 200px );
                width:100%;
                background:yellow;
            }
            
            .titlediv
            {
                height:200px;
            }


        </style>
        
        
        <div class="maindiv">

                <div class="titlediv">
                    Title 1
                </div>
                
                <div class="maindiv-inner-content">
                
                
                </div>


        </div>


    </body>

</html>
```

Basically you need to remove the margin from the `body`, otherwise if you set the div to `100vh` you will get a scrollbar.

Then you can use `calc` to make the height of the div you want too be 100% - height-of-titlediv.

I removed the `maindiv-inner` as I did not understand what it was there for, so I just thought it was unnecessary.
Also the `relative` positioning seemed unnecessary so I removed that as well.

Comment: This does not seem to work well in codepen but it definitely works fine in my browser, I 
believe that the issue is that `vh` in codepen refers to the whole window naturally whilst your content is only displayed in the iframe at the bottom

Comment: using a calc funtion works as a solution but also has it downside for responsivness. If the title height change, then the whole calculation will be wrong and the design messed up. If borders, paddings or margins are added, the calc function will also calculate the wrong values and the design will be broken. Therefor you should use a calc function always in combination with `box-sizing: border-box;`. However this will leave the solution still un-responsive to adept to a possible changing title height.

Comment: Thanks tacoshy, you are making some good points :) , my solution with calc anyways relied on having the constant height of 200px (since that was in the question and thought it needed to be that way) so responsiveness anyway was a bit out of the question (unless of course for the addition of some media queries).

Comment: I didnt downvoted it as it currently fulfils the OP's question. However it would be wise not to only answer the question that it works but having potencial further issues in mind. IMHO this makes the difference between good and bad web developers. Good ones can not only solve an issue but also prevent further issues. Therefor I strongly recommend you to add `box-sizing: borderbox;` to your code as I can garuntee you, that the op going to use some kind of paddings sooner or later.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :), on stackoverflow I answer the questions by trying to only solve what's been asked and try to not change much else as much as possible because I assume the other elements are already set that way for a reason, I shall keep in mind what you said as it's a constructive criticism which makes a lot of sense thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

simple way to achieve the bahavior is the use of either flexbox or CSS-Grid. With CSS-Grid you declared the grid as 2 rows by `display: grid; grid-template-rows: min-content auto;`. The title row will have the hieght `min-content` means that it will only take up as much height as needed or declared. The 2nd row with the hight of `auto` will take up all remaining height by default.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.maindiv {
  background: red;
}

.maindiv-inner {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: min-content auto;
  background: blue;
}

.maindiv-inner-content {
  background: yellow;
}

.titlediv {
  height: 100px; /* changed for demo */
}
```

```html
<div class="maindiv">
  <div class="maindiv-inner">
    <div class="titlediv">
      Title 1
    </div>
    <div class="maindiv-inner-content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```